# Angle between two planes, finding the second plane

Tags: solid-geometry

I've got a plane given by $x-y+z=0$ and a line given by $r=(0,0,a)+t(1,1,b)$.

> How do I find another plane that contains the line and intersects the other plane at an angle of $45^\circ$?
>
> Is the vector $s=(1,1,b)$ perpendicular to both vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ of the two planes where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the normals of the two planes?

Comment: How did you come up with the vector $s$?

Comment: Depending on the line specified, it might not be possible to find such a plane.